# How to find "Days since Sunday" with the JavaScript Date() object

Tags: javascript, date, dst, weekday

The `tm_wday` (e.g., weekday) property on the C++ time structure `struct tm` represents days since Sunday, an integer from 0-6. This is often used in daylight savings calculations; e.g., "The first Sunday in November."
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/

How is the equivalent calculated in JavaScript? In other words, how can "Days since Sunday" be found using a JavaScript `Date()` object?

I Googled around, and checked the MDN docs, but there does not appear to be an equivalent method.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Is anyone aware of a polyfill or `get_days_since_sunday()` method that has been written? Is there an easy way to do this, or do I need to write it? Thx, Keith :^)

Comment: Note that if you're going to use this for any "Nth day of the week" purposes, know that not everyone starts their week on Sunday.

Comment: As Tom scott said in the [Computerphile video about timezone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY), you should always find a library that does that.  i suggest momentJS function `moment().day()` that returns exaclty that.

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple way to find number of days between today and last sunday.
Feel free to ask me if you have any question.

```
var date = new Date();
date.getDay();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Date#getDay` to return the zero-based index of the weekday, starting with Sunday:

```
new Date.getDay() // returns 2, if today is a Tuesday
```

Comment: ... which was actually in the documentation the OP linked!

Comment: Ah ok I see it... tyvm I was looking for a "days since sunday" type of thing. Too many hours of C++ today.